# For the given power sum $ \left( \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{K-1} x^k \right)^n$, what is the coefficient of $x^{m}$ term?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, power-series, education

For the given power sum $ \left( \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{K-1} x^k \right)^n$, what is the coefficient of $x^{m}$ term ?

Let

$ \left( \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{K-1} x^k \right)^n = \displaystyle \sum_{m}^{} a_m x^m $

Then $a_m=?$

Comment: Here K and n are positive integers

Comment: What is $ \displaystyle \sum_{m}^{} a_m x^m $ I mean what are the limit's start and end exactly?

Comment: Zero for $m>n(K-1)$ ;-)

Comment: $\displaystyle \sum_{m=0}^{n(K-1)} a_m x^m$

Comment: may help: for $x\ne 1$, $$\sum_{k=0}^{K-1}x^k=\frac{x^K-1}{x-1}$$

Comment: If $m<K$ the answer is easy, because the $m$-the coefficient is the same than that of $(1-x)^{-m}$

Answer (score 1):

In terms of Iverson brackets and falling Pochhammer symbols,$$a_m=[x^m]\left(1-x^K\right)^n(1-x)^{-n}\\=\sum_{a,\,b\ge0}(-1)^{a+b}\binom{n}{a}\frac{(-n)_b}{b!}[Ka+b=m]\\=n\sum_{a=0}^{\max\left\{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{K}\right\rfloor,\,m\right\}}(-1)^a\frac{(n+m-Ka-1)!}{a!(n-a)!(m-Ka)!}.$$I'm not sure we can get a nicer expression than that for the integer $a_m$, except when $K\in\{0,\,1\}\lor n=0$.

Comment: That's probably as reasonable as answer as we can get. There will be a sum somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start.
I may do more later.

$\begin{array}\\
s_m(x)
&=\left( \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} x^k \right)^n\\
&=\left(\dfrac{1-x^m}{1-x} \right)^n\\
&=\dfrac{(1-x^m)^n}{(1-x)^n}\\
&=(1-x^m)^n\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+i-1}{j}x^i\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}(-1)^{n-j}x^{m(n-j)}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+i-1}{j}x^i\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}(-1)^{j}x^{mj}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+i-1}{i}x^i\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}(-1)^{j}x^{mj}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+i-1}{i}x^i\\
\end{array}
$